# google maps I don't see all street name with zoom 15

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I'm using google maps api v3 to add shapes and markers to a map
The I use google maps static map api to get the image of that map and print it
The problem is that with zoom 15 I see the whole area but I don't get all streets name of that area.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=24.8147642107468,-107.375049591064&zoom=15&size=640x440&scale=2&format=png32&language=es&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:0xff0000|24.8165756517471,-107.376508712769&path=color:0xffffe1|weight:2|fillcolor:0xffffe1|enc:samvC~nlnS?{K}\s@aPqNyDkH}@aK|@aGzAcEdBiC`GeEeCuLlBwFpEr@hFuAl]ePjD~Bw@xJlAl_@pGlLeC`VmAh]{KX
```

[link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=24.8147642107468,-107.375049591064&zoom=15&size=640x440&scale=2&format=png32&language=es&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:0xff0000|24.8165756517471,-107.376508712769&path=color:0xffffe1|weight:2|fillcolor:0xffffe1|enc:samvC~nlnS%3F%7BK%7D%5Cs%40aPqNyDkH%7D%40aK%7C%40aGzAcEdBiC%60GeEeCuLlBwFpEr%40hFuAl%5DePjD~Bw%40xJlAl_%40pGlLeC%60VmAh%5D%7BKX)

With zoom 16 I get all streets name but the area doesn't fit in the image

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=24.8147642107468,-107.375049591064&zoom=16&size=640x440&scale=2&format=png32&language=es&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:0xff0000|24.8165756517471,-107.376508712769&path=color:0xffffe1|weight:2|fillcolor:0xffffe1|enc:samvC~nlnS?{K}\s@aPqNyDkH}@aK|@aGzAcEdBiC`GeEeCuLlBwFpEr@hFuAl]ePjD~Bw@xJlAl_@pGlLeC`VmAh]{KX
```

[link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=24.8147642107468,-107.375049591064&zoom=16&size=640x440&scale=2&format=png32&language=es&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:0xff0000|24.8165756517471,-107.376508712769&path=color:0xffffe1|weight:2|fillcolor:0xffffe1|enc:samvC~nlnS%3F%7BK%7D%5Cs%40aPqNyDkH%7D%40aK%7C%40aGzAcEdBiC%60GeEeCuLlBwFpEr%40hFuAl%5DePjD~Bw%40xJlAl_%40pGlLeC%60VmAh%5D%7BKX)

How can I resolve this?

Saludos
rubenc

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

As you have discovered, you can't use the staticmap api to get the image you want. So you have to do it another way. Request multiple images and stitch them together in whatever interface you are creating?

Comment: Not even wiith Google Maps Apis for Work? It says that I can get images with scale 4 and size 2048 x 2048